# Power supply makes a repetitive noise under heavy load

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, gpu, desktop-computer

Here's the noise my PSU makes:

https://youtu.be/4E8P5ZOfYZA

As you can hear it's loud when I put the microphone right next to the PSU, but barely noticeable when I'm sitting at my desk right next to the PC. I've read other answers saying that it could be Coil Whine, but the sound they are describing is totally different.

What could be causing this specific sound?
Should I be concerned?

---

I haven't overclocked any of the components, which are all new and the PC works fine so far. I haven't experienced any shutdowns or overheating.

Components:

- PSU: `EVGA 600 BR, 80+ Bronze 600W`
- CPU: `Intel Core i3-8100`
- GPU: `GIGABYTE AORUS GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER 8GB`

Loads:

- GPU usage: `80%`
- GPU temperature: `75°C`
- GPU voltage: `1037mV`
- CPU usage: `100%`
- CPU temperature: `55-60°C`

Comment: The noise you are hearing is not coil whine (I have this myself and it drives me crazy, but age of my PSU is why I have this issue...), I will say this is likely to be the fan due to the increase in heat as you have said this happens whilst under load. As to whether you should be concerned or not I cannot give a clear answer, I would contact EVGA and ask about the noise level whilst under load, if still under warranty it may be best to get something done about it now rather than wait until it does develop a severe fault and have to pay for another PSU.

Comment: @CraftyB I contacted EVGA as you suggested and indeed it seems to be the fan causing this noise. Thanks!

Comment: Besides the air noise, the only other thing I could hear in the recording is a sound a little bit like a rattle.  If that's what you're referring to, then you've nailed it in your answer.  That's more typical to hear when the fan is old due to wear.  It can also be caused by getting some dust stuck to one of the fan blades.  It's just enough weight and air resistance that it unbalances the fan and makes it wobble a little at high speed (which will make the bearings wear faster).  You can inspect it and try to clean it (will probably require a little disassembly for good access).

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes I was referring to the rattle. Thanks for your input. The only problem is that my PSU is brand new and there's no dust. I checked it and my PC case has done a good job of catching the PSU dust. Maybe it was unbalanced from the beginning....? I'll definitely keep an eye on it though in case it gets worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted EVGA support and they reassured me that this noise is of no concern and it is most likely caused by the bearing of the fan. They also offered me the option to return the product if the noise is bothering me, which I didn't choose since in my case it's barely noticeable.

I'll update this answer if something new comes up.

Comment: Update! I upgraded to a `Corsair RMX 850 Watt`, which switches off the fan at low and medium loads and now it's totally silent. Even at high loads I don't hear a similar sound anymore...